# Python script loops after done executing imported script

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

My end goal is that, after the main Python script finished executing, start the imported script and if the user Ctrl-C'd exit.
However, after the main Python script finished executing the imported script, it immediately started again, like in a loop.
I'm pretty sure that all the code and logic of the two programs is unnecessary, but how I import them is not:

Imported script:

```
def start():
    app.run(debug = True)
```

Main script:

```
import script_2.py
.
.
.
script2.start()
exit()  # Doesn't Work
```

I think it is also worth noting that the imported script is a Flask script, so until the user Ctrl-C'd the program should not be terminated.

Comment: Your code doesn't run so it's hard to tell what you're trying to do. Give us a minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: The main script is a selenium script, after it ends the imported flask script is starting, but in the middle of the execution of it, the main selenium script executes again for some reason. Example of script ending: 
```* Serving Flask app "app2" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with stat
   Welcome to my program  # Example of main script starting again
```

Comment: `app2.start()` looks wrong. Did you mean `script2.start()`? Understand that these inconsistencies throw people off and you'd be less likely to get any help

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice, Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`debug=True` will restart your app if you make any changes in `script_2.py`. See: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#debug-mode

Remove it if you don't want this behavior.

Comment: @yahavbahat please hit the green tick if it helped, thanks

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure about the terminology. My way of implementing it is a different way of OOP or import. So If anybody has the right terminology for that please provide it (sorry I'm boon). 
Basically we are using subprocess to call script_2.py. 'r' in in windows.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(
                [r'path\to\python.exe',
                 r'path\to\script_2.py', var_1, var_2)
```

You catch var_1 with sys.argv[1], and var_2 with sys.argv[2] in script_2.py.

Now for the tricky part. you need to use pickle to provide a file with a counter.
In script_1.py:

```
counter_file = 'counter'

def unpickle_database(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        while True:
            try:
                yield pickle.load(f)
            except EOFError:
                break  



def return_counter():
    count = list(unpickle_database(counter_file))
    try:
        return count[0]
    except IndexError:
        return 0

def save_counter(counter_file):
    raw_counter = return_counter()
    final_counter = counter + raw_counter
    with open(counter_file, 'wb') as output:
        pickle.dump(final_counter, output, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

        while running:
            if return_counter() < int(threads.get()):
                counter += 1
                save_counter(counter_file)
                if not running:
                    break

                proc = subprocess.Popen(
                    [r'path\to\python.exe',
                     r'path\to\tor_money.py', var_1, var_2)
```

In script_2.py:

```
counter_file = 'counter'

def unpickle_database(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        while True:
            try:
                yield pickle.load(f)
            except EOFError:
                break


def return_counter():
    count = list(unpickle_database(counter_file))
    for number in count:
        return number

## end your process here

raw_counter = return_counter()
print(raw_counter)

final_counter = raw_counter - 1
with open(counter_file, 'wb') as output:
    pickle.dump(final_counter, output, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
print(final_counter)
```